# Avoid space and special characters except comma in Kendo autocomplete mvc wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo autocomplete mvc wrapper into which I'm taking input in the form of comma delimited string and I have to validate and show error when somebody enters white space or special character except comma.

Below is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                                .Name("searchids")
                                .Filter("startswith")
                                .Placeholder("Enter Feed ids...")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:230%;height:50px" })
                                .Separator(", ")
                    )
```

Comment: Add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to property `searchids` so you get both client and server side validation

Comment: How to do that Stephen,please provide any code as I'm new to this. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a pattern to the html attributes:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("searchids")
.Filter("startswith")
.Placeholder("Enter Feed ids...")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:230%; height:50px", @pattern="^[\w,\-]+$" })
.Separator(", ")
)
```

Comment: I tried following- **.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:230%;height:50px", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter Feed Id(s)",pattern="^[\w,\-]+$" })**
but its not working @Ziregbe Otee :(

Comment: Please paste the html that is generated on your browser. It must have the pattern attribute else it won't work. Something like:  <input type="text" name="searchids" pattern="^[\w,\-]+$">

Comment: i did it this way-
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:230%;height:50px", required = "required", pattern = "[0-9a-zA-Z,]+" })

Answer (score 1):

Add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to your property

```
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9,]*$")]
public string searchids { get; set; }
```

and add

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.searchids)
```

in your view to give you both client and server side validation.

Side note: I'm not familiar with Kendo.AutoComplete, but some similar plugins hide the original input and replace it with their own html, in which case you may need to configure the `jQuery.validator` to validate hidden inputs if your not getting client side validation.

Comment: I haven't bind my view with any model. Now what should I do?

Comment: Well you need to (and why on earth didn't you?). If you do not have a model, just create a view model - `public class MyModel` with that property and then in the view add `@model MyModel`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke is right. You should use view model, so that server side validation is also applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poojadhanani/x4a3pz04/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [
      "Albania",
      "Andorra",
      "Armenia",
      "Austria",
      "Azerbaijan",
      "Belarus",
      "Belgium",
      "Bosnia & Herzegovina",
      "Bulgaria",
      "Croatia",
      "Cyprus",
      "Czech Republic",
      "Denmark",
      "Estonia",
      "Finland",
      "France",
      "Georgia",
      "Germany",
      "Greece",
      "Hungary",
      "Iceland",
      "Ireland",
      "Italy",
      "Kosovo",
      "Latvia",
      "Liechtenstein",
      "Lithuania",
      "Luxembourg",
      "Macedonia",
      "Malta",
      "Moldova",
      "Monaco",
      "Montenegro",
      "Netherlands",
      "Norway",
      "Poland",
      "Portugal",
      "Romania",
      "Russia",
      "San Marino",
      "Serbia",
      "Slovakia",
      "Slovenia",
      "Spain",
      "Sweden",
      "Switzerland",
      "Turkey",
      "Ukraine",
      "United Kingdom",
      "Vatican City"
    ];

    //create AutoComplete UI component
    $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
      dataSource: data,
      filter: "startswith",
      separator: ", ",
      placeholder: "Select country...",
      change: function() {        
        var value = this.value();
        var data = this.dataSource.view();
        console.log(value);
      }
    });

    $("#countries").keypress(function(event) {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9,]*$");
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.k-autocomplete {
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  .hint {
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #7496d4;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>

<input id="countries" />
<div class="hint">Start typing the name of an European country</div>
```

Comment: you can't type spaces in this example. Eg try : "United Kingdom"